# Calling same route on submit

Tags: laravel

I dont know why I am facing this issue.
I have a table where I called new route to open a update view that is

```
 Route::get('update_view/{id}', ['as' => 'update_view', 'uses' => 'admin\study_material\StudyMaterialController@update_view']);
```

And after submit the form below route is called

```
Route::post('update/{id}', ['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'admin\study_material\StudyMaterialController@update']);
```

Now, issue is when update page is called it is showing update page correctly,but when form is submitted i get error use of post method is not allowed.Use Get or Put.But I check url it is showing me update_view/3 instead of update/3.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'StudyMaterial', 'as' => 'StudyMaterial.'], function () {
    Route::get('view', ['as' => 'view', 'uses' => 'admin\study_material\StudyMaterialController@view']);
    Route::get('add', ['as' => 'add', 'uses' => 'admin\study_material\StudyMaterialController@add_view']);
    Route::post('add_studyMaterial', ['as' => 'add_studyMaterial', 'uses' => 'admin\study_material\StudyMaterialController@add']);
    Route::get('update_view/{id}', ['as' => 'update_view', 'uses' => 'admin\study_material\StudyMaterialController@update_view']);
    Route::post('update/{id}', ['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'admin\study_material\StudyMaterialController@update']);
});
```

My Form :

```
<form action="{{ route('StudyMaterial.update',$data[0]->id) }}" method="POST" class="text-center" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<button type="submit>Update</button>
</form>
```

Generated Url :

1. To View Form to update fileds =>
   localhost/project/public/StudyMaterial/update_view/13
2. To redirect Url to submit form to controller =>
   localhost/project/public/StudyMaterial/update/13

after submitting form URL 2 should generate.But here it is showing only Url 1 which is GET method.
This is happening in my whole project.
Thank You in advance

Comment: Try to add `@method('POST')` in the form.

Comment: Change order of route. First `Route::post('update/{id}'....` then `Route::get('update_view/{id}'...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="{{ route('StudyMaterial.update',$data[0]->id) }}" method="POST" class="text-center" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <button type="submit>Update</button>
</form>
```